# Modifying a UIButton width with animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uibutton, width

Here is my code ,

```
-(IBAction)casser{
     oeuf1.contentMode       =   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ 
         CGRect newRect      =   oeuf1.frame;
         newRect.size.width *=   5;
         oeuf1.frame         =   newRect;
         [oeuf1 release];
    }];
}
```

"oeuf1" is a UIButton
I want to multiply its width by five when I touch the button, but when I do that the button moves  to the right and its width doesn't change. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you releasing `oef1`?

Comment: Good point, that [ouef1 release] seems wrong.

Comment: thanku for this question i have learned something specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested code 100% works**

connect each method with specified

```
-(IBAction)expand{//touch down


    NSLog(@"expand");

    [UIView transitionWithView:but duration:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void) {


        CGRect newRect = but.frame;

        CGPoint ce= but.center;
        newRect.size.width *= 5;

        but.frame = newRect;    

        but.center=ce;



    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {



    }];


}

 -(IBAction)shrink{//touch up inside
    NSLog(@"shrink");


    [UIView transitionWithView:but duration:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void) {


        CGRect newRect = but.frame;

        CGPoint ce= but.center;
        newRect.size.width /= 5;

        but.frame = newRect;    

        but.center=ce;



    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {



    }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The working answer:

Remove `[oeuf1 release];`

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use

```
[oeuf1 setFrame:CGRectMake(oeuf1.frame.origin.x, oeuf1.frame.origin.y, oeuf1.frame.size.width*2, oeuf1.frame.size.height)];
```